# Quantlib Python Yield Curve bootstrapping issue

Tags: python, date, quantlib

I'm using Quantlib to calculate the price of a swap. Before calculating the swap price I create quantlib curves which are used during the calculations.

Unfortunately I get a RuntimerError: RuntimeError: 2nd leg: 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar April 4th, 2023, maturity April 4th, 2023, reference date September 30th, 2022: root not bracketed: f[0.600742,1.66461] -> [1.241044e-02,1.241044e-02].

On github/stackoverflow I see that many others have encounterd the same problem in which the rate needed to divide by 100 or the quantlib date wasnt set correctly. It looks like I encounter another problem which I cannot solve.

Also when I only use yearly rates (so not monthly rates) the code runs fine and gives me an answer. Any help is much appreciated.

I use the code below:

```
from QuantLib import *
import pandas as pd

today = Date(30, September, 2022)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

def create_ql_curve():
    estr_short = pd.DataFrame({'Tenor': [6], 'Rate': [1.7466]})
    estr_long = pd.DataFrame({'Tenor': [1,2,5,10,15,20], 'Rate': [2.2828, 2.547, 2.661, 2.804, 2.85, 2.35]})
    euribor_short = pd.DataFrame({'Tenor': [6], 'Rate': [1.7466]})
    euribor_long = pd.DataFrame({'Tenor': [1,2,5,10,15,20], 'Rate': [2.2828, 2.547, 2.661, 2.804, 2.85, 2.35]})

ois_helpers = [OISRateHelper(0,
                             Period(int(tenor), Months),
                             QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                             Eonia(),
                             YieldTermStructureHandle(),
                             True)
               for rate, tenor in zip(estr_short['Rate'], estr_short['Tenor'])]

ois_helpers += [OISRateHelper(0,
                              Period(int(tenor), Years),
                              QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                              Eonia(),
                              YieldTermStructureHandle(),
                              True)  # telescopicValueDates. When set to True bootstrapping is a lot faster.
                for rate, tenor in zip(estr_long['Rate'], estr_long['Tenor'])]

discount_curve = PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, TARGET(), ois_helpers, Actual365Fixed())

discount_curve.enableExtrapolation()

helpers = [SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                          Period(int(tenor), Months),
                          TARGET(),
                          Annual,
                          Unadjusted,
                          Thirty360(),
                          Euribor6M(),
                          QuoteHandle(),
                          Period(0, Days),
                          YieldTermStructureHandle(discount_curve))
           for rate, tenor in zip(euribor_short['Rate'], euribor_short['Tenor'])]

helpers += [SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                           Period(int(tenor), Years),
                           TARGET(),
                           Annual,
                           Unadjusted,
                           Thirty360(),
                           Euribor6M(),
                           QuoteHandle(),
                           Period(0, Days),
                           YieldTermStructureHandle(discount_curve))
            for rate, tenor in zip(euribor_long['Rate'], euribor_long['Tenor'])]

euribor_curve = PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, TARGET(), helpers, Actual365Fixed())

euribor_curve.enableExtrapolation()

return discount_curve, euribor_curve

discount_curve, euribor_curve = create_ql_curve()

forecast_handle = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(euribor_curve)
discount_handle = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(discount_curve)

index_6M = Euribor6M(forecast_handle)
swap_engine = DiscountingSwapEngine(discount_handle)

#  swaps

start_date = Date(23, April, 2014)
maturity_date = Date(23, April, 2023)
fixed_schedule = Schedule(start_date, maturity_date,
                          Period(1, Years), TARGET(), Unadjusted, Unadjusted,
                          DateGeneration.Forward, False)

floating_schedule = Schedule(start_date, maturity_date,
                             Period(6, Months), TARGET(), ModifiedFollowing, ModifiedFollowing,
                             DateGeneration.Forward, True)

notional = 115000000
fixed_rate = 0.01727
fixed_leg_daycount = Actual360()
float_spread = 0
float_leg_daycount = Actual360()

calendar = TARGET()
previous = calendar.advance(today, -27, Weeks)
dates = [calendar.advance(previous, n, Days) for n in range(150)]
rates = [0.005] * 150

for date, rate in zip(dates, rates):
    index_6M.addFixing(date, rate)


swap = VanillaSwap(VanillaSwap.Receiver, notional,
                   fixed_schedule, fixed_rate, Thirty360(),
                   floating_schedule, index_6M, 0.0, Actual360())

swap.setPricingEngine(swap_engine)

price = swap.NPV()
```

Comment: Pretty sure I heard you answer your own question. The package is buggy w.r.t. monthly rates, but solid on an annual basis. Use the appropriate conversion factor to turn your monthly into yearly rates. Also, please include the bug-report URL in this question, and consider putting together a patch / pull-request to repair the upstream source code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: I tried to use the SwapRateHelper for monthly rates which doesnt work. When making a curve using monthly rates you should use the following:

```
helpers = [DepositRateHelper(QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                             Period(6, Months), 3,
                             TARGET(), Following, False, Actual360())]
```

instead of:

```
helpers = [SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate / 100)),
                          Period(int(tenor), Months),
                          TARGET(),
                          Annual,
                          Unadjusted,
                          Thirty360(),
                          Euribor6M(),
                          QuoteHandle(),
                          Period(0, Days),
                          YieldTermStructureHandle(discount_curve))
           for rate, tenor in zip(euribor_short['Rate'], euribor_short['Tenor'])]
```